# Why is this offtopic?

Tags: discussion

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/25087/what-online-banks-i-can-use-if-i-am-in-indonesia

I am in Indonesia and I need a foreign bank account I can control via internet.

What is so unrelated to money this is?

Many people ask complex questions like whether they should withdraw their 401k, etc.

Why not me?

Answer (score 5):

"Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic."

You are asking for shopping advice.  You happen to be asking for shopping advice on a service or company with a particular feature, but it is shopping nonetheless.

See also:  https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/851/91

Comment: And shopping questions are timely and likely to be out of date in a short period of time.

Comment: I disagree that this counts as asking for recommendation. I am not asking which banks that is best. I am asking which bank fits some criteria http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/848/what-counts-as-recomendation?lq=1

Comment: @JimThio - I am sorry you see a difference, but the fact you are asking "which banks meet a criteria" is still shopping and still off topic.