# What counts as recomendation?

Tags: discussion

The way I understand is

if I need something, say A. If there are 10  things that fulfill it, and I want the one that's best, then it's a recommendation.

If I ask, A, and there is nothing that fulfill it. I don't even know whether A exist or not.

I do not think that's recommendation. It's no longer subjective.

Even things that you actually use is not subjective. That's because the idea that you uses A1 is a fact.

What do you think?

Sample question is here:
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/25087/what-online-banks-i-can-use-if-i-am-in-indonesia

I am not asking for the best foreign bank for Indonesian. I am asking for any bank that can be controlled online from Indonesia,

What's the best bank for this is **subjective**
What banks can be used for this is **objective**.

What do you think?

Answer (score 8):

Your answer, even in your example, is too localized and based on a period of time.  If at some point (presumably) Internet Banking does take off in Indonesia, that particular question will not be a service to the site as written.

Keeping with the stackexchange goal of 'making the Internet better', that question only helps you.

(Please don't read my answer with a mean, punitive or dismissive tone; I don't intend it that way.  I believe I am enforcing the rules as written.)

Perhaps a better question would be seek **how** to solve your problem:

"I am having a hard time finding a comprehensive listing of banks and their services in Indonesia.  Is there a government list, rating agency or officially maintained database that will show me banks, the services they provide and maybe even fees"

That might not be what you want, that might not be a good question.  My point is you can probably get the information you seek, if you take your question from a different angle.

Comment: +1 It's all about perspective. I've rewritten many questions and made them acceptable by changing the perspective of the question.

Comment: I do not need online banks in Indonesia. I need an online bank accessible from Indonesia. That's not localized. Any banks accessible from Indonesia will also be accessible from India and many other places.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question was not clear and part was asking for recommendation and hence got closed.

Well as you already know, Internet Banking in Indonesia has not taken off for a variety of reasons.
As I understand your intent is to find a Bank outside Indonesia that have online internet banking so that you would use to make transfers.
There maybe quite a few Banks in Singapore and other countries that may allow you to open an account. But then the question is how would you transfer to money into this Foreign Bank. There would be currency loss.

Comment: All currency will be in dollar. Would you help modify my questions? Basically I need a foreign bank. That foreign bank must be controlled online because well, I don't want to have to go to that country every time I want to send wire.